# Finding all Controls on a Page

Tags: asp.net

If I start with

```
Page.Controls
```

Then recursively call all the children control.Controls, will the guarantee that I find all the controls that exist on a given page. Are there any time that orphaned controls can exist, or any other controls that will not show up when iterating through the page's controls in this way?

Even if this is correct is there a better way of finding all of a page's controls?

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: "Even if this is correct is there a better way of finding all of a page's controls?"  Perhaps it'd help if you tell us why you want to find all of the controls on the page?  If you're asking for an opinion on good style it'd help to know what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: ASP multiline textbox's maxlength attribute does not validate, i was working on a legacy project that had used that throughout assuming that it would work, I thought it would be a quick fix to find all those controls and attach javascript that corrected the issue, I understand that perhaps creating a custom control with proper validation is probably the correct thing to do, I was just looking for a band-aid at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will find all the controls that exist when you ask. There's nothing to say that more controls won't be added later, after DataBinding, for instance.

Maybe you want to check in the OnPreRenderComplete method?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, this will give you controls with runat=server specified.  It won't give plain old HTML controls.

Answer (score 1):

I use [ControlFinder](http://rapidshare.com/files/253192688/ControlFinder.cs) helper for access to all my children controls. Get it and adapt to your code.